# API command to make a VSCode extension download file from URL

Tags: visual-studio-code, download, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to make an extension in Visual Studio Code, that would download a file from a specified URL - the idea is for the extension to automatically install a few other extensions, by

1. checking if an extension is installed,
2. if not, download a .vsix file

I tried using the "node-fetch" API, but it generates errors whenever I do the base usage

```ts
fetch('https://github.com/')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(body => console.log(body));
```

The error is that **Parameter 'res' implicitly has 'any' type**.

I tried using a file downloader extension "mindaro-dev.file-downloader", but it also fails right at the beginning, since the basic usage states I should do

```ts
import { getApi, FileDownloader } from "@microsoft/vscode-file-downloader-api";
```

but when I do, I get an error:
**Cannot find module '@microsoft/vscode-file-downloader-api' or its corresponding type declarations**.

Is there any vscode API command available that handles the file downloads or is it more complicated than that? Or maybe using this vscode file downloader is a good lead but I'm not fulfilling some prerequisites?

Comment: Sounds like you were just missing `npm install @types/node-fetch`.

Answer (score 1):

using npm

```
npm install @microsoft/vscode-file-downloader-api
```

or using yarn

```
yarn add @microsoft/vscode-file-downloader-api
```

then the problem should be fixed

see: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-file-downloader-api/issues/12#issuecomment-819134615

Comment: Hi! Yes, that's what I was missing, thank you!